# HTML/Wordpress plugin to help content managing

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am not sure if this is the place to ask but i wanna build a restaurant site for a friend, However he wants to himself be able to change the menu around if in a years time it changes etc, In WordPress is there an easy plugin which allows you to do that?  Or does it have to be done manually?

For example  if there is an easy content managing system out there? Im really dont use word press so im not sure , i mostly code

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to do this would be using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. It allows you to create custom fields, so that you can create custom areas that the client could edit, without breaking the styling of the site.